SAP Odata Metadata Cache
As we know, we clear the metadata of OData services after every deployment or release. Clearing the metadata cache using a few standard UI5 programs has been very helpful. However, we are experiencing significant latency when users log in for the first time after each deployment.
Is there a way to rebuild the metadata cache after clearing these services to mitigate this latency issue?
How can we rebuild the metadata cache?
For fast loading times of SAP Fiori apps, cache buster tokens are used to cache OData metadata (metadata and annotations documents). To ensure the tokens are up-to-date, report /UI5/UPD_ODATA_METADATA_CACHE has to be executed periodically.
I read the above but not really sure if this is the right way to proceed.

What says the SAP Support?

Hey Sandra, it does load the metadata cache, tried to do a POC and it went well. Apologies for the late response!

Thanks for the feedback. For information, you may delete your question, see here: I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?.
